# jQuery append php html string returned by Codeigniter's controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have array of string returned by Codeigniter's controllers upon user's login.
Some of the string(s) are in html format. I would like to append those strings to html element when there is an event done by the user.

Here is the example of the html string in php variable returned by controller

```
$form_dropdown = form_dropdown('selCat_GP[]', $subcats2,'0', 'class="selCat_GP"');
                $Dropdown_GP = '<div class="tr">'
                                    . '<div class="td">Category :</div>'
                                    . '<div class="td">'. $form_dropdown .'</div>'
                                    . '<div class="td">Sub Category :</div>'
                                    . '<div class="td">'
                                    .   '<select class="selSubCat_GP" name="selSubCat_GP[]">'
                                    .       '<option value="0" selected="true">-Select a category first-</option>'
                                    .   '</select>'
                                    . '</div>'
                                    . '<div class="td">Score :</div>'
                                    . '<div class="td"><input class="score" name="score_GP[]" value="0" type="number" size="1" step="10" min="0" max="100" maxlength="2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="btnRemove">Remove&nbsp;[-]</a></div>'
                            . '</div>';
```

and what I did in jQuery is :

```
jQuery('#preference'+preference).append(<?php echo json_encode($Dropdown_GP); ?>);
```

But it gives me this error
[image]

I have tried to add both single quote and double quotes but it gives me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    jQuery('#preference'+preference).append('
    <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
jQuery('#preference'+preference).append("
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
```

Do you how can I echo the php html string and append it to html element in the view using jquery (when there is an event fired) ?

I know I can use ajax post to request the data from the server instead of returning it beforehand. It is just because the same data will be requested often so I don't wish to give more work to the server. I just need to load it one time and just simply display it when user requests it.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add quotes to $.append statement

Comment: I have tried both single and double quotes but they don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.
Since I placed the jQuery script right after body and before my html codes, all the variables returned by codeigniter controller are not recognized by jQuery.
There are two steps to solve my problem :

1. Place the jQuery after html code but before the closing tag of body
2. I still need to use json_encode(..) to avoid any break line of html string and it is used without any single nor double quotes.

Thank you everyone for the answers and comments

Answer (score 0):

You missed single quotes.

```
jQuery('#preference'+preference).append('<?php echo json_encode($Dropdown_GP); ?>');
```

Comment: it does not work. It returns a different error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.     jQuery('#preference'+preference).append("
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

Comment: I see double quotes in your comment instead of single.

Comment: There might be some issues in `json_encode($Dropdown_GP)`. Test it with alert and see what you get. It's saying undefined variable in your screenshot right?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes, I just tried:

```
$('#header').append('<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">Stackoverflo,ooo,ooow</div> ');
```

on this SO page (replaced **#preferences** with **#header**) and it worked without any problem.

Please check again it string you are trying to append is quoted correctly.

Comment: I have checked the string (I posted here) for a few times now. It is well structured

Comment: ah I missed it, there is warning thrown in your PHP code for undefined variable... Please have a look.

Comment: but when I echo it in my view file (not through jQuery) it is just fine

Comment: and in the error log there is a line break. the <div> tag is just not attached to the single quote but displayed as a new line

Comment: you are trying to `json_encode($Dropdown_GP);` something that contains special characters ? 
I think `jQuery('#preference'+preference).append('<?php echo $Dropdown_GP; ?>'); ` should work fine

Comment: yes that too is a problem because if you look at output, warning is multi-line, but, I am thinking of undefined variable error displayed in your Javascript code

Comment: I have tried without using json_encode before still the same issue

Comment: Maybe the way to get the php variable returned by codeigniter's controller is not correct

Comment: I guess..because the jQuery is loaded first before the data returned by the controller. That's why all the variables returned by the controller are not recognized by jQuery